# Firebase iOS Swift: Updating TableView After Removing A Child

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I have a tableview that shows children of a reference. How can I update the tableview when a child is removed? The child can be removed from other devices and I want the tableview updates automatically. I know there is observe .childRemoved but not quit sure how to use it to update the tableview.

Comment: you can use `FUITableViewDataSource` (`FirebaseDatabaseUI`)

Comment: just reload your tableView at end of database Handler you are using to get Children

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used observe childRemoved. Then in the block, I emptied the array, reloaded the tableview, and called ref.observe .childAdded again.

```
ref.observe(.childRemoved, with: {(removedData) in 
            array.removeAll()
            tableView.reloadData()
            fetchUserRequests()
        })
```

Answer (score 1):

By using: 
`self.tableView.reloadData()`

e.g. From an old project where I was playing with a sync'd list.

```
self.ref.child("familys").child(currentUserData.family).child("list").observe(.value, with: { (DataSnapshot) in

        if DataSnapshot.hasChildren() == false{
            print("No list")
        }

        else{
            self.list = DataSnapshot.value as! [String]
        }
        self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Everytime something below the level of "shoppinglist" updates, this observe block of code is called. self.tableView.reloadData() recalls all the functions such as

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
    return(list.count)  
}
```

Hope this helps.